# How to Publish ASP.NET Core WEB API Project on Local IIS in Visual Studio 2017 Community RC?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to publish ASP.NET Core WebAPI Project with swagger on IIS. i want to run the Project on local machine with IP Address.

Configuration of My PC is:
Visual Studio 2017 Community RC
Windows 10
IIS

Please help me.

Comment: Hi did you manage to get this working then in the end?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ["this one (learn.microsoft.com)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis)?
It helped for me. Don't forget to configure authentication and access to your site physical path for application pool identity you are going to use.

**UPD (reply to comment):**
In case you're using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package you can try somethig like this in your ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services):

```
// Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    var info = new Info
    {
        Title = "My web API",
        Version = "v1.0",
        Contact = new Contact()
        {
            Email = "foo@gmail.com",
            Name = "Denis",
            Url = "https://stackoverflow.com"
        },
        Description = "My API"
    };
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", info);
    var basePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory; // this is not equal to wwwroot folder due to WebHostBuilder settings
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "MyApi.xml");
    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
});
```

And in Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory):

```
// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwagger();

// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1.0/swagger.json", "My web API v1.0");
    c.EnableDeepLinking();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I have already tried this link its helpful for simple ASP.NET Core project. 
But my project includes "Swagger" http://swagger.io/. So I need solution for that.